# FlatList not visible even if i added it in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have added searchview then another row below that and then i have added flatlist in my view below the horizontal listview and i want to show it in full remaining height but it is not showing, there is also not any error in the code and also it doesn't show any error in console, here is a code :

```
 <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

    <View style={styles.searchView}>

      <TextInput
        style={styles.searchInput}
        onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
        value={this.state.searchText}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        placeholder="Search Services"
        placeholderTextColor={theme.colors.app_blue_light}
      />

      <Image source={Images.search} style={styles.searchImage} />
    </View>

    {/* MapView */}
    <View style={styles.MapToggleContainer}>

      <Text style={styles.titleShop}>Select your shop</Text>

      <Text style={styles.titleToggle}
        onPress={this.toggleView}>List View</Text>

    </View>

    <View style={styles.shopListView}>

      <FlatList
        horizontal
        style={styles.shopsList}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item: rowData }) => {
          return (

            <View style={styles.shopListItem}>

              <Image source={require('./logo.png')} style={styles.shopImage} />

            </View>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      />

    </View>

    <MapboxGL.MapView>
      <MapboxGL.Camera centerCoordinate={this.state.coordinates[0]} zoomLevel={14} />

      <MapboxGL.MarkerView id='marker1' coordinate={this.state.coordinates[0]}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('./chat.png')}
          style={{ borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 0, width: 80, height: 80, alignContent: 'center' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ toolTipVisible: true })
            }}>
            <Tooltip
              animated
              isVisible={this.state.toolTipVisible}
              content={<View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                  <Image source={require('./chat.png')} />
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 10 }}>123, Main st,</Text>
                    <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>Chicago, IL 6061</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', margin: 10, alignItems: 'center' }}
                  onPress={() => { }}
                >
                  <Text style={{ margin: 10, color: 'white' }}>Select Shop</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>}
              placement="top"
              onClose={() => this.setState({ toolTipVisible: false })} >

              <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }} >$50.00</Text>

            </Tooltip>

          </TouchableOpacity>

        </ImageBackground>

      </MapboxGL.MarkerView>

    </MapboxGL.MapView>

 </View>
```

Styles

```
mainContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.white
    },
toggleContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      marginTop: '20@ms',
      marginBottom:'10@ms',
      marginHorizontal: '15@ms',
    },
    titleShop: {
      fontFamily: 'Muli-Bold',
      fontSize: '16@ms',
      color: theme.colors.gray4
    },
    titleToggle: {
      fontFamily: 'Muli-Bold',
      fontSize: '11@ms',
      color: theme.colors.gray4,
      textDecorationLine: 'underline',
      alignSelf:'center'
    },
MapToggleContainer:{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      marginTop: '10@ms',
      marginBottom:'15@ms',
      marginHorizontal: '15@ms',
    },
    shopListView:{
      height:'60@ms'
    },
    shopsList:{
      marginLeft:'5@ms',
      marginRight:'15@ms',
    },
    shopListItem:{
      elevation:5,
      backgroundColor:'white',
      marginLeft:'10@ms',
      height:'50@ms',
      width:'50@ms',
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent:'center',
      borderRadius:'5@ms'
    },
    shopImage:{
      width:'30@ms',
      height:'30@ms',
    },
```

And here is a result, as you can see the mapview below list is not visible

[image]

Comment: Try wrapping it inside a view with flex:1 and a background colour to verify. You can use react-dev-tools to identify and change styles as you do on the web inspector.

Comment: Did you get your solution by my answer

Answer (score 0):

give `height` and `width` style to `MapboxGL.MapView`

```
<MapboxGL.MapView style={{width:Dimensions.get("window").width,height:400}}>
```

Comment: I don't want fix height, i want to fill it in remaining screen

Comment: you can use flex:1 in style

Comment: or you can also use dimension api to make dynamic hight like this height:Dimensions.get("window").height-usedHeight-offset;

Comment: in mapbox official example is also using flex:1 https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/adba9bec8fb006e95a6cc35266c0a5eb171db5d5/example/src/styles/sheet.js